# Search using Grep in Perl

Tags: perl

I have the below code. I need to search if todaydate is present in the filterdates. However, the below code is not working. Could you please help, what I'm missing?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use strict; 
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper; 
my @filterdates={FD=>'08/30/2020',TD=>'08/31/2020'}; 
my $todaydate='08/30/2020'; 
 
if ( grep{/^$todaydate$/} @filterdates) { 
        print Dumper ("Found"); 
}
```

Comment: `@filterdates` should be a hash not an array (with a single hashref) ?

Comment: Agreed. I modified the below line 
my @filterdates={FD=>'08/30/2020',TD=>'08/31/2020'};  to
my @filterdates=('08/30/2020','08/31/2020');  and it worked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> my @filterdates={FD=>'08/30/2020',TD=>'08/31/2020'};
> ```

There are a couple of problems here.

Firstly, `@filterdates` is an array variable. But `FD=>'08/30/2020',TD=>'08/31/2020'` looks like you want to use it as a hash.

Secondly, both arrays and hashes are initialised using a list:

```
my @filterdates = (FD=>'08/30/2020',TD=>'08/31/2020');
```

Or

```
my %filterdates = (FD=>'08/30/2020',TD=>'08/31/2020');
```

You're using `{ ... }` to initialise your array. `{ ... }` gives you a reference to an anonymous hash. So your array contains a single element that looks like `HASH(0X1234567890AB)` and that's never going to match your date string.

If you can be a bit clearer about what you're trying to do, then we can probably help you fix it.